# Is there an ordering to user supplied matplotlib canvas callbacks via mpl_connect?

Tags: python, canvas, matplotlib, callback, event-handling

I register 2 callbacks - 1 for clicking and 1 for picking.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', onclick)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
...
def onclick(event): ...
def onpick(event): ...
```

I wanted to know in my click event whether or not it occurs with a pick event, (knowing that clicking on a pickable object triggers both events). I noticed that the pick event always comes first, so I check / set a variable like `clicked_point = True # or False` in `onpick` and `onclick`.

This works fine so far but seems sketchy. I couldn't find an answer in the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/), but perhaps I have simply have not found the right section yet.

My alternative would be to only register `'button_release_event'`, and calculate Euclidean distances between click coordinates and data points on my `scatter` plot to determine if the `'pick_event'` behavior should be evoked. I'd rather rely on a call order for these functions registered with `mpl_connect` if it does indeed exist.

I've come across code that checks if an event is in a set of artists (`ax.collections.contains(event)` or something similar). However, since I use a single call to scatter with the full array of data points (`plt.scatter(X, Y, ..)`), I am returned a single `PathCollection` object, which I understand represents a path for all the points in the order they came in. However I could never quite figure out to get indivual artists from this collection, so when I check for `event` containment in `[PathCollection]`, it always returns false. Not sure if something like this was even doable or if it makes sense, but I figured I'd document it here in case it was relevant.